# Why is the length of a cable-type radio-antenna usually determined by c/f regardless of the preceeding pcb trace length?

Tags: antenna, radio

especially when dealing with low power IoT-devices or these arduino-style radio-modules that don't come with fixed rod-like antennas but rather those cable-type antenna-tails, the length of the antenna-cable is described as a critical factor for the signal range - and is calculated by dividing the speed of light by the signal frequency. 
I wonder though, wouldn't the length of the pcb-trace leading towards the antenna-connector need to be included in the length-calculation as well?
If not, how is it that the receiving part only begins at the antenna-connector?

Comment: Do you understand transmission line theory? If not AND you want a decent answer then start learning it. Dividing c by f usually gets you a monopole antenna length that is 4 times too big. Do some more research is my advice. It's not a simple subject.

Comment: yep, you're asking "why is the transmission line to the antenna not part of the antenna", and that can only be honestly be answered with "because it's a matched transmission line and not an antenna", unless you want us to write a complete introduction to transmission line theory.

Comment: @tobias Because you get maximum power transfer when the source impedance is matched with the load.